# Python: validate if csv has only one column else throw error

Tags: python, email, email-validation

I have a CSV file containing emails in which i need to validate if there are more than one columns, if there are then i need to reject the file, I was thinking of reading each line and using "in" operation to check if first row contains comma , although in one of the yahoo link https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101211183849AAy3gVh
i found that we can have commas in email address if in double quotes.

What should be the logic here?

can't use csv or pandas module

first 3 rows of file:

```
dilkash.manghani@gmail.com, dilkash.manghani@gmail.com
dilkash123@gmail.com, dilkash123@gmail.com
dilkash423@gmail.com, dilkash523@gmail.com
```

code:

```
with open("file.csv", "r") as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
    for email in data:
        if "," in email:
            raise Exception("invalid")
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post your code

Comment: i read the file, parsed each row and verified if there is comma in any row, not sure why it is down voted though, does somebody know the answer

Comment: show us how your input file looks like, and show what you have tried till now

Comment: added first few lines of file

Comment: @dilkash, it can't be a valid csv, if it includes commas in a column then,it should be surrounded by a double quote

Comment: Why don't you simply discard any quoted strings, then look for any remaining commas? `sed -n 's/"[^"]*"//g;/,/p' filename` (This is arguably still too crude for all the weird wonderful corner cases of RFC 5322, but might still be good enough in practice.)

Answer (score 0):

use pandas, load into a data frame as below

```
import pandas 

df = pandas.read_csv(file_path)
if (len(df.columns) >2):
    raise Exception
else:
    print("Valid")
```

EDIT: Since, you can't use pandas or csv, you can do the following

```
with open(file) as f:
    for each in f:
        if len(f.split(',"')) > 2:
            raise Exception
    print("Valid CSV")
```

Note: i used `,"` as the separator. why?, because, since if a comma can be included in a column, it is supposed to be surrounded by double quotes. And since its a csv, each column has to be separated by a comma. hence, it would atleast have one `,"`

Comment: can't use pandas

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         assert(len(row) == 1)
...         print ', '.join(row)
```

will do the job.

Comment: Why change the quote character to a pipe and the delimiter to a space?

Comment: It is just an example, you have to use the values that fit your csv

Comment: can't use csv module